# How to prevent logback from outputting its own status at the start of every log when using a layout

Tags: logback

This seems like a carelessness error, but I can't seem to find the cause. Logging with logback/slf4j (most recent version slf4j-api-1.6.1, logback core/classic 0.9.24). Simplest log configuration for testing is:

```xml
<configuration>
 <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
   <!-- DONT USE THIS FORMATTER FOR LIVE LOGGING THE %L LINE NUMBER OUTPUTTER IS SLOW -->
   <pattern>%le %-1r [%c{1}:%L] %m%n</pattern>
  </layout>
 </appender>
 <root level="DEBUG">
  <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
 </root>
</configuration>
```

Every log setup starts with logback's internal status lines:

```
11:21:27,825 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
11:21:27,826 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback-test.xml] at [file:.../logback-test.xml]
11:21:28,116 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
11:21:28,124 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
11:21:28,129 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [stdout]
11:21:28,180 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Pushing component [layout] on top of the object stack.
11:21:28,206 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[stdout] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
11:21:28,206 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[stdout] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
11:21:28,206 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[stdout] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
11:21:28,207 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to DEBUG
11:21:28,207 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [stdout] to Logger[ROOT]
```

which is, according to the docs, the format logback uses for default. It then finishes reading the config (which is set up to output a different format) and continues with the properly formatted output.  There's a config parameter `<configuration debug="false">` which does not affect this.

Anyone know how to shut this off?

Comment: Recent versions of logback are much faster at calculating %L.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the docs say "L / line : Generating the line number information is not particularly fast. Thus, its use should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue." FWIW: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html (so maybe it's faster but still not super fast or something...)

Comment: @rogerdpack yes. It is found by analyzing a stack trace of an exception. That has become faster.

Answer (score 305, accepted):

If you set the `debug` attribute of the `configuration` element to `true`, you will get all status information to the console. If this is your problem, just set it to false or remove it.

If you have any configuration problems of level `WARN` or above, you will also get all status information logged to the console (including messages of level `INFO`). The best solution to this problem is to fix the problem (in your case replace the `<layout>` element with an `<encoder>` element).

If you for some reason cannot fix the problem, but want to remove the status-information from the console, you can instead configure an alternative `StatusListener`. Use the `NopStatusListener` to completely remove the status-information:

```xml
<configuration>
  <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />
  <!-- etc -->
</configuration>
```

Comment: This worked. I wasn't entire clear that the `INFO` log messages would disappear, too, but in fact they do. I know the answer says this, but for some reason it wasn't clear to me. To be oh-so-clear: fix the encoder/layout problem and not only will the warning messages go away, but the info messages will go away, too, even though they are unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Did not work with the debug attribute, but worked flawlessy with the status listener.

Comment: Careful using this approach, it appears to work but it hides the fact that you have a configuration error in your file.  The real problem is the WARN logs, these issues should be fixed in config, then all the logs inc. INFO go away.

Comment: Definitely `status listener` is the way to go. @Steve B., what's wrong with accepting the answer?

Comment: My slf4j is usually quiet by default, but I was having trouble quieting the output in my unit tests.  Then this answer reminded me that I'd copied a line from my prod config that was setting up an OnConsoleStatusListener.  So all I had to do was remove that.

Comment: In my case INFO logs were caused by "hidden" WARN log about Large window sizes (too big number in rollingPolicy).

Comment: `NopStatusListener` will suppress everything, not just the initialization that the OP wanted to remove

Comment: @ArtemBilan "what's wrong with accepting the answer?" I cannot answer for the OP, but for me it simply does **not** work. I added `<statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />` to `logback-text.xml` and still I can see the messages `INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve[null] - Could NOT configuration file ...` (sic! with the missing "find") etc.

Comment: @HonzaZidek When using Logback-access under Tomcat, you have to add the configuration to a file name logback-access.xml, which should be located in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/ next to the server.xml-file. Just creating the file will probably work, but otherwise try with the options above.

Comment: @RasmusFaber I posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/65035615/2886891, because I believe that it is either a different problem or that your solution here does not work. (I also tried adding `<statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />` to `logback-text.xml` as you suggested here but with no good result.)

Comment: that status listener element doesn't just work anywhere in the xml file, needs to be up top. What a relieve! All those logback messages were super annoying every time I ran unit tests

Answer (score 49):

As [described in the docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#automaticStatusPrinting), if warnings or errors occur during the parsing of the configuration file, logback will automatically print status data on the console.

Follow http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder i.e. 
the link mentioned by logback in its warning message. Once you follow the steps mentioned therein, that is, if you replace <layout> element with <encoder>, logback will stop printing messages on the console.

Comment: Sort of right, although you did point me in the right direction. I'd changed to that encoder syntax without effect, although it turns out that removing another line in the logback.xml that was causing a warning did the trick. The deceptive thing about it is that the output seems to be outputting decisions made before it actually parses your logback file, (1>Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy],2>Found resource [logback-test.xml]). It's pretty confusing for a fix in the logback-test to hide status messages for what happens before it gets parsed. But thanks for the pointer.

Comment: The warning comes from the deprecated <layout> element as the warning clearly states. I am afraid I cannot make sense of your last comment.

Comment: I think what Steve B. meant is that it's counterintuitive (or at least unconventional) that Logback should suppress *all* status messages, including (and particularly) those that precede the loading of the configuration file, unless it encounters an error later in the configuration.  When you are unfamiliar with this rule and first see these status messages (which imply a configurtion warning or error), most users would expect that once the error is resolved, Logback would no longer print the related error messages, but continue to print the other status messages.

Comment: @Steve B.: In case you are curious, I asked a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401051/suppress-all-logback-output-to-console.

Comment: FWIW, i also find this quite confusing behaviour. The spew of INFO level messages does a pretty good job of hiding the ERROR messages telling me what i actually need to fix. The lack of a DTD, or any other specification of the syntax of the configuration file, made it quite a trial to debug even once i spotted the message.

Comment: @Ceki: I'm in the same position as binkley in this same post: logback output is only INFO and yet I can't make it go away. Can you please suggest a remedy? I'm using logback-classic/core-0.9.24 and slf4j-api-1.6.1 .

Comment: @Ceki: I finally figured it out: The 2nd way to trigger these messages is to have the `debug="true"` attribute in the `configuration` element of `logback.xml`. Please mention this for the benefit of other people who fall into this hole!

Comment: Perhaps before the first INFO statement there should be a 'Warning detected, outputting all past status info.  To stop this message, fix your warnings/errors'

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem i added this line

```
        <!-- Stop output INFO at start -->
        <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />
```

in the logback and it succefully worked

Comment: This works, however it prevents ERROR messages output too - no output is produced when serious logback configuration problem occures.

Answer (score 8):

**Ceki** answer is correct:

> (...)if warnings or errors occur during the parsing of the configuration file, logback will automatically print status data on the console.

Once you get it right, there won't be any pollution in the first lines of your log anymore.

As of March 2015, in **Logback 1.1.2**, you need to use `<encoder>` sub-component - `<layout>` is now deprecated and if use it, error messages will appear. You cannot control this, it´s **Logback** default behavior.

Some internal classes have been renamed too, and even the examples in their manual page are outdated!

Here is the code snippet from their *Errors Code Help page*, which has the correct way to config the logger. This fixed the issue completely in my project.
http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
  <file>testFile.log</file>
  ...
  <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
    <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to use status listener in order to switch off own logback logs:

```
<configuration>
  <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />
  ...
</configuration>
```

But as was mentioned **NopStatusListener** also prevents showing warning and errors. So you can write your **custom status listener** and change log level for it manually:

```
package com.your.package;

import ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener;
import ch.qos.logback.core.status.Status;

import java.util.List;

public class PrintOnlyWarningLogbackStatusListener extends OnConsoleStatusListener {

    private static final int LOG_LEVEL = Status.WARN;

    @Override
    public void addStatusEvent(Status status) {
        if (status.getLevel() == LOG_LEVEL) {
            super.addStatusEvent(status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        final List<Status> statuses = context.getStatusManager().getCopyOfStatusList();
        for (Status status : statuses) {
            if (status.getLevel() == LOG_LEVEL) {
                super.start();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then use it in your logback.xml file:

```
<configuration>
  <statusListener class="com.your.package.PrintOnlyWarningLogbackStatusListener" />
  ...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6):

I realized Steve found the fix but he didn't mention it on the thread. In case if any other person hit the same issue here is the fix.

Replace **"<layout>"** elements with **"<encoder>..</encoder>"**

The culprit is:
**<layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">**

Comment: If you want to completely remove those messages, use the NopStatusListener as Rasmus described. The encoder vs layout approach does not suppress messages such as 'logback.groovy not found' for example. I'm using logback-classic 1.1.3 (March 2015)

Answer (score 4):

Struggled with the same problem myself i.e. there were a bunch of lines logged right at the beginning which were not related to my code. Here is how I fixed it.

```
<configuration debug="false">

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- <encoder> <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level 
        %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern> </encoder> -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{10} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>

<logger name="fun.n.games" level="DEBUG" />
```

This is running with the following entry in the pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be Fixed in 0.9.29. Just made several tests. No Joran INFO anymore. I guess [this](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/commit/8be92873) is the fixing commit.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried everything and nothing worked for me. My problem was due to multiple logback.xml files in my classpath. This is the common case in multi modular projects.
When there is only one logback.xml file in classpath, there is no ambiguity and the problem is solved.

Comment: what output did it give you?

Answer (score 0):

Using the **`logback.groovy`: `statusListener(NopStatusListener)`** (in the `src/test/resources/logback.groovy`) works.

(A valid use case is e.g. if working with ANT in Eclipse, using logback logging, groovy classes and unit tests where the unit tests take the `src/test/resources/logback.groovy`, but will also see the `src/main/resources/logback.groovy` (or similar) you cannot exclude (if ANT's classpath is said to use the projects classpath).)

Answer (score 0):

Just for people landing here because of the status messages logged by `ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve#LogbackValve` (recent versions). Just set the `quiet` flag:

```java
var v = new LogbackValve();
v.setQuiet(true); // disable status messages!
v.setFilename("logback-access.xml");
```

See also the [documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/access.html#tomcat) for XML configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need logs in file instead of console you can redirect it by adding statusListener in logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnFileStatusListener" />
  ...
</configuration>
```

It will add "status.txt" file with logs in root of your working directory.

You can create your own listener which will write logs to the destination you like:

```
public class OnLogsDirFileStatusListener extends OnFileStatusListener {

    private static final String DIR = "logs";

    public OnLogsDirFileStatusListener() {
        try {
            Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(DIR));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        setFilename(Path.of(DIR, "status.log").toString());
    }
}
```

and then specify it in your logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <statusListener class="path.to.your.listener.OnLogsDirFileStatusListener" />
  ...
</configuration>
```