# Suppress all Logback output to console?

Tags: java, configuration, logback

How can I configure Logback to suppress all of its output to the console (standard output)?  In particular, I wish to suppress (or redirect) Logback's own log messages such as the following:

```
16:50:25,814 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
16:50:25,814 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/opt/dap/domains/ap0491/uat1/domain/instance-config/logback.xml]
16:50:25,816 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
16:50:25,816 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [file:/opt/dap/domains/ap0491/uat1/domain/instance-config/logback.xml]
16:50:25,816 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [file:/opt/dap/domains/ap0491/uat1/domain/instance-config/logback.xml]
16:50:25,923 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
16:50:25,924 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.ReconfigureOnChangeFilter@1a15291 - Will scan for changes in file [/opt/dap/domains/ap0491/uat1/domain/instance-config/logback.xml] every 60 seconds.
```

I need to disable all logging to standard output because our production environment disallows applications from printing any messages to standard output.

Note I'm using Logback 0.9.21, SLF4J 1.6.0, and our application runs in WebLogic 10.3.2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Holger Hoffstätte was correct in his [diagnosis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401051/suppress-all-logback-output-to-console/3404644#3404644) that the duplicate classpath entry message is a symptom of a [bug](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LBCLASSIC-159) in how Logback counts classpath entries.  Robert Elliot also [characterized](http://marc.info/?l=logback-user&m=128094084217480&w=2) the problem in a [thread](http://www.qos.ch/pipermail/logback-user/2010-August/001716.html) on the Logback [user mailing list](http://www.qos.ch/pipermail/logback-user/).  According to Robert and others in this related [disussion](http://bugzilla.slf4j.org/show_bug.cgi?id=138) on the SLF4J mailing list, when an application that uses Logback runs in a WebLogic container, due to the way the WebLogic classloader operates, Logback reports duplicate classpath entries for the `logback.xml` configuration file.  However, regardless of whether the WebLogic classloader should or should not report only unique classpath entries, Logback should certainly count only unique classpath entries so that it does not print this confusing, spurious message.

I have implemented a [fix](http://github.com/derekmahar/logback/commit/1990e7c9c0e35ba408f73a2c654e8d292a0849af) for [LBCLASSIC-159](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LBCLASSIC-159) that essentially does what Robert Elliot recommends and uses a set instead of a list to hold the resources that the classloader returns, effectively eliminating any duplicate classpath resources.  I have successfully tested the fix with Logback 0.9.24, SLF4J 1.6.1, and WebLogic 10.3.2.  As Thorbjørn predicted in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401051/suppress-all-logback-output-to-console/3401238#3401238), with this fix in place, Logback no longer displays the duplicate classpath entry status messages (or any of the other informational messages) to standard output.

I hope that the maintainers will integrate my fix into the main Logback [source code repository](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback) and include it in the next release.

Comment: Thank you Derek. your patch fixing the issue will ship in [tag:logback] 1.0.4

Answer (score 46):

Those messages only show if at least one of the following is true:

- you have debugging enabled in the logback.xml file
- you have an error in your configuration.  That is the case here - logback complains about multiple configuration files found.
- there is a classpath problem if your environment provides conflicting files. (this one occurred to me yesterday and was the real cause of this question).
- (there is a bug in logback - has happened)

Correct the issue and those messages should go away.

Comment: What about the `INFO` messages?  I see many more of those than the warnings.  I just listed a sample.

Comment: How can I redirect the warnings to standard error (or another file) instead of standard output?

Comment: Then you have more problems with your logback configuration.  Fix them and the messages will go away.  I do not believe the messages can be redirected - have a look in the logback source to see.

Comment: Actually the messages always show up if there are multiple configurations on the classpath (which is the reason for the warning but often a completely legitimate situation), and logback currently does NOT pick one but rather reverts to default settings. Please also see my comment at http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LBCLASSIC-130?focusedCommentId=11801#action_11801

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Logback outputs these messages to standard output even before it has completely read the configuration file (apparent from the message "debug attribute not set"), so I cannot see how my Logback configuration can be to blame for the informational messages.  I'll do as you suggest and look at the Logback source code to see what it does at startup.

Comment: Another thought:  might I suppress these messages by turning off the root logger or by attaching it to an appender that writes to a file?

Comment: What you see is Logbacks _internal_ logging which is completely decoupled from whatever you choose to do.  It is normally not printed anywhere, _except_ when an error occurs during the configuration phase in which case it is listed to Standard out.  So, just _fix_ what it complains about, and it will not appear.

Comment: @Holger, why is it a legitimate situation, and which logback.xml file should logback have picked?

Comment: @Holger:  I'm certain that Logback uses one of the two configuration files that it finds on the classpath and according to Ceki Gulcu's comments (http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LBCLASSIC-130?focusedCommentId=11799#action_11799) in the thread to which you refer, it uses the first one that it finds.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Yes, I agree that this is Logback's internal logging.  So you say that when Logback detects a configuration error, it outputs not only its error or warning messages, but all of its internal log messages (including those that occur before the error, for example, "Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]")?

Comment: Yes, see http://logback.qos.ch/manual/joran.html.  "If and only if there are warnings or errors during the parsing of the configuration file, logback will automatically print status data on the console".  If you read the messages carefully you can identify what is wrong, and fix it so the messages will go away.

Comment: Also note that the "Could NOT..:" is INFO, not WARN.  This is simply to aid, not a problem.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: According http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LBCLASSIC-85?focusedCommentId=10987#action_10987, Logback class `ContextInitializer` is responsible for printing these log messages, so I'll review its source code to see how it works and determine whether there is some way I can disable the output.  If not, I may make a request to the developers to give users the option to suppress or redirect these messages (at least the `INFO` messages).

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Yes, "Could NOT find resource..." is an `INFO` message and does not indicate a problem, but I would still like to suppress or redirect these messages and any other messages that Logback prints to standard output because our production environment disallows all standard output.

Comment: @Derek, if no ERROR or WARN messages are generated the INFO messages are _not_ printed.  Hence, eliminate the underlying reasons that triggers the ERROR and WARN messages, and this output - including INFO and DEBUG messages - goes _ENTIRELY_ away.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Understood, but according to Robert Elliot in http://qos.ch/pipermail/logback-user/2010-August/001719.html, this duplicate classpath message may actually be a bug in Logback, so eliminating these messages may be easier said than done.

Comment: Very interesting.  He sees this with WebLogic.  What container do you use?

Comment: Sounds like WebLogic brings its own implementation - which is fine - but which also is put on the class path for web applications. Can you simply use that instead of bringing your own binding?

Comment: @Thorbjørn  I eliminated the cause of the one ERROR message in the Logback startup log entries.  But that did not make the INFO log entries go away:-(

Answer (score 15):

This is a "me too" answer, sorry!

Happily, I've found a solution (see UPDATE) below.

Contrary to some of the other answers, I'm getting a stream of LogBack configuration `INFO` messages in spite of having no `ERROR`s or `WARN`s in the configuration phase.

Here are my messages:

```
13:39:20,457 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
13:39:20,457 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
13:39:20,457 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/home/carl/workspace-LSY/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/IceProfile/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
13:39:20,496 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.ReconfigureOnChangeFilter@14e2c9c - Will scan for changes in file [/home/carl/workspace-LSY/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/IceProfile/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml] every 60 seconds. 
13:39:20,496 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
13:39:20,497 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
13:39:20,501 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
13:39:20,510 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
13:39:20,510 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Pushing component [encoder] on top of the object stack.
13:39:20,537 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to DEBUG
13:39:20,537 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
13:39:20,538 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [ch.qos.logback] to OFF
13:39:20,538 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [ch.qos.logback] to false
13:39:20,538 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
```

Here's my configuration:

```xml
<configuration debug="true" scan="true"> 

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <!-- encoders are  by default assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
  
  <logger name="ch.qos.logback" level="OFF" additivity="false" />
  
</configuration>
```

This is spam I don't want, I consider myself innocent of having provoked it, and I'd appreciate some help in getting rid of it.

One respect in which I may be "guilty" is that I'm initializing my loggers in a `static` variable; the docs recommend using instance variables instead.

Versions:

- logback-classic-0.9.24.jar
- logback-core-0.9.24.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
- executing in an IceFaces 2.0 app running in Tomcat 6.0 under Ubuntu 11.04

---

**UPDATE**

Finally figured out what the problem was!

From [the fine manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/onJoran.html) (and [Thorbjørn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3401238/1102512)):

> **Setting the debug attribute** within the  element will output status information, under the assumption that
>
> 1. the configuration file is found
> 2. the configuration file is well-formed XML.

My mistake was

```xml
<configuration debug="true" scan="true">
```

In retrospect, *duh!* Hopefully this information will help others.

Answer (score 11):

```
<configuration>
<statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />
</configuration>
```

Simplely use NopStatusLinstener class and this will stop self logging of logback.

Comment: This is not working for me. I'm using syslog4j library to send logs on server.

Answer (score 8):

So I had the same problem but found that removing the incorrect <layout /> entry which was deprecated somewhere around 0.9.4 and the messages went away...

You appender should look some thing like

```xml
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

 <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
  <level>info</level>
 </filter>

 <encoder>
  <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd} %d{HH:mm:ss} %.-1level %thread %logger{36}: %m%n</pattern>
 </encoder>

</appender>
```

I've blogged about a more [complete](http://softwareontheinside.blogspot.com/2010/09/suppress-logback-initialisation.html) description of what I changed that worked for me

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my Logback configuration contains no `<layout/>` elements.  None of its appenders include threshold filters, either.  Only the loggers filter according to threshold.

Comment: Did you try adding an 'info' threshold filter on console?

Comment: 15:09:07,610 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Logback. But if it's printing to `System.out` or `System.err`, these are simply public static `PrintStream` variables in the `System` class. You could subclass `PrintStream` and set the system output variables to your subclass, thus controlling how it works.

For example:

```
public class NOPPrintStream extends PrintStream
{
    public NOPPrintStream() { super((OutputStream)null); }

    public void println(String s) { /* Do nothing */ }
    // You may or may not have to override other methods
}

public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out = new NOPPrintStream();
        // Start program
    }
}
```

(This code is untested)

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply this solution to my particular case.  My application runs inside a WebLogic container, so `main()` is not my application entry point and I don't know how WebLogic "starts" the application.  Furthermore, I don't know how WebLogic or Logback may set the `System.out` and `System.err` variables.

Comment: Well, you could set `System.out` in your code (presumably you know the first section of **your** code which runs), and the worst thing that could happen is that it doesn't work :)

Comment: WebLogic may invoke one or more optional initialization methods in an application at startup, but I'll have to investigate which ones these may be.  Our application does not have any such initialization routines.  Our application consists of two sub-systems: a Web application that receives Web service requests and forwards them to an EJB application that processes the request, accesses a database, and sends a response back to the Web application.  Both of these use Logback to log their activities, and each must have its own separate initialization process.

Comment: I suppose that if I'm unable to identify which routines WebLogic invokes at startup, I could sets `System.out` in the static initializer of some singleton class.  That way I'd be certain that my application would invoke it exactly once (assuming that it uses the class).

Comment: Note that one disadvantage of this approach is that it will disable all standard output for every environment, but we need to disable it only for our production environment.

Comment: Giving it some more thought, I could always conditionally redirect `System.out` using a system property that specifies the current environment.

Comment: Your `PrintStream` subclass also doesn't necessarily have to be NOP, it was just example code :)

Comment: System.out is also final in my JDK - you should use `System.setOut()`.  I used this for a quick hack `System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {public void write(int b) {}}){});` (you can't pass a null outputstream).  The idea works for me though, at least for a quick and dirty hack!

Answer (score 2):

Actually the fact that the same logback.xml location is reported multiple times seems more like a bug in logback than anything else. Either report this to the logback JIRA ([here](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK)) or first check whether the jar in question is on the classpath multiple times.

Comment: First, I'll check with our administrators to see why our WebLogic server instance sees the Logback configuration location twice on the classpath.  The `logback.xml` file is not actually in a jarfile, but exists outside the EAR in a separate location.

Comment: No, that is a deliberate decision by the logback designer.

Comment: I agree, I think that reporting the multiple classpath locations is actually a useful message and not a bug.

Comment: The messages quoted report the same physical location twice.  I vaguely recall to have seen this before as being a fixed bug.  Double check that you are using the latest version of logback.

Comment: @Holger: According to Robert Elliott in http://marc.info/?l=logback-user&m=128094084217480&w=2 and http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LBCLASSIC-159, this may actually be a bug in Logback or SLF4J (or both).  I'm using Logback 0.9.21, but will upgrade to 0.9.24 to see whether this fixes the problem.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Do you happen to have a reference to the Jira item that resolves duplicate classpath entry issue?

Comment: The reason that this happens in Logback may be the same reason why it causes http://bugzilla.slf4j.org/show_bug.cgi?id=138 in SLF4J.

Comment: After reviewing the code, this problem still exists in Logback 0.9.24: http://github.com/ceki/logback/blob/v_0.9.24/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/util/ContextInitializer.java and http://github.com/ceki/logback/blob/v_0.9.24/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/util/Loader.java.

Comment: It's important to point out that users have reported this problem when running their applications inside WebLogic or Resin.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you register and comment that this is a production issue for you, to LBCLASIC-159 issue.   If this is a showstopper you might even purchase support for Logback from QOS.ch (not affiliated, just suggesting) to get immediate attention.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: I fixed LBCLASSIC-159.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401051/suppress-all-logback-output-to-console/3411015#3411015.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had the "logback-test.xml" in a dependent project that was being deployed as a webapp jar.
The "logback-test.xml" file started with

```
<configuration debug="false" scan="true">
```

The 'scan="true"' attribute generated this error:

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.ReconfigureOnChangeFilter@716de067 - URL [jar:file:/C:/Local...cut.../WEB-INF/lib/My.Dev.jar!/logback-test.xml] is not of type file
```

which resulted in 67 (!) more INFO lines.

By removing the 'scan="true"' attribute, the logback log disappeared altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a  element configured in your logback.xml. You can remove it, if you don't want any console updates about the state of the logging framework itself. Though, logback framework recommends against disabling it for troubleshooting purposes.

There is an alternative to the console listener called StatusListenerAsList which keeps the status messages as a private list. You can expose it via JMX, if needed, with a little bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add information about default header message added in logback 1.0.2:

```
#logback.classic pattern: %d [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
```

I found that in [logback news](http://logback.qos.ch/news.html), but it was really difficult to find.

If you wish to remove this message, you have to set up `outputPatternAsPresentationHeader` to false:

```xml
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0}: %msg%n</pattern>
        <!-- do not print pattern as a header -->
        <outputPatternAsPresentationHeader>false</outputPatternAsPresentationHeader>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the following error logs in my spring boot application:

```
14:37:36,455 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:46 - no applicable action for [springProfile], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile]]
14:37:36,456 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@6:92 - no applicable action for [include], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][include]]
```

I suppressed them by either:

- renaming `logback.xml` to `logback-spring.xml`
- or, define in `application.properties`: `logging.config=classpath:logback.xml`

---

Spring documentation on this topic:
[image: spring description]