# Spring boot, logging a specific package to file and not to console

Tags: logging, spring-boot

I want to log a specific package just to file, instead of to console too.

This specific package generate a lot of log entries, because of this I don't want to pollute console with that messages. I need that log to trace an "random strange bug".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [Spring Boot logging documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html).
All modern logging frameworks supported by Spring Boot such as Logback or Log4j are super-easy to configure for such cases...

For example using Logback you would do something like that :

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FilAppender">
        <file>/var/log/my-app.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

You can also check this other answer to [suppress all logback output to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401051/suppress-all-logback-output-to-console), mine is just an example.