# Spring Boot Unit Test ignores logging.level

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback

One of my maven module ignores my logging levels when running tests.

In `src/test/resources` I have `application.properties`:

```
app.name=bbsng-import-backend
app.description=Import Backend Module for Application
spring.profiles.active=test

# LOGGING
logging.level.root=error
logging.level.org.springframework.core =fatal
logging.level.org.springframework.beans=fatal
logging.level.org.springframework.context=fatal
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=error
logging.level.org.springframework.test=error
logging.level.org.springframework.web=error
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

I also tried `application-test.properties`.

My Application logs a lot, especially when loading context. I tried `logback.xml`, `logback-test.xml` and `logback-spring.xml` but nothing helps.

My pom:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>at.company.bbsng</groupId>
    <artifactId>bbsng-import</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>bbsng-import-backend</artifactId>
<name>bbsng-import-backend</name>

<properties>
    <start-class>at.company.bbsng.dataimport.ApplicationImportBackend</start-class>
</properties>


<dependencies>

    <!-- APPLICATION ... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>at.company.bbsng</groupId>
        <artifactId>bbsng-app-domain</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING ... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JAVAX ... -->
       ...

    <!-- COMMONS ... -->
       ...

    <!-- LOMBOK ... -->
       ...

    <!-- DB -->
       ...

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.boot-version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

One simple Test class:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ApplicationImportBackend.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles({ "test" })
public class BatchJobConfigurationTests {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Test
    public void testSimpleProperties() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(jobLauncher);
    }

}
```

Application logs is in DEBUG Mode.

And yes, the `application.properties` will be loaded. I already tried to break the application by wrong config.

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Okay what I did now, in all modules I configured as follows:

**src/main/resources:**
I use logging configuration in `application.properies` like `logging.level.*` as described in the question.

**src/test/resources:**
I use `logback-test.xml` like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <logger name="*.myapp" level="error" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.core " level="error" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.beans" level="error" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.context" level="error" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.transaction" level="error" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="error" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.test" level="error" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="error" />
</configuration>
```

But I still don't understand, why in few modules I could use application.properties, but in another module it ignores ... But for now it works for me as it is.

But maybe few hints with background knowledge are still welcome.

I dont mark my answer as solution, cos it still feels like a workaround.

Comment: My assumption is that `application.properties` is being parsed later than test initialization. That's why `org.springframework.test` has no effect on initial test logging.

Comment: This is awesome. I added `<logger name="org.springframework.boot" level="warn" />` and `<logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="warn" />` to really minimized the noise. If you're using swagger, you can also add `<logger name="springfox" level="warn" />`. Well done. Have a bounty!

Comment: This helped, although I started seeing a bunch of logs from logback itself after I tried adding the `logback-test.xml` file. To turn those off [I followed the main answer from this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257154/how-to-prevent-logback-from-outputting-its-own-status-at-the-start-of-every-log) - and BAM, I've managed to get rid of all the precursory logging when running tests.

Comment: My `logback-test.xml` file was as simple as this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <statusListener
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />
  <include
    resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
  <logger name="org.springframework" level="error" />
</configuration>

Comment: Same Problem. 2 Moduls with exactly the same Configuration (base class). One has logging during context creation, the other not. Changes in application.properties (logging.level) take effect.
Using above `logback-test.xml` works as expected. (+1) thanks

Comment: @DannyBullis, you may also simply omit the `include resource` line to prevent logback metadata from being logged.

Comment: Stumbled on this post, has a similar experience. From what I have found, test slices etc. which may not bootstrap the entire spring context also do not necessarily load application.yml/properties. Couldn't say for sure if the times you're finding that it's not working are that.

Answer (score 48):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
</configuration>
```

As a fast fix, I put `logback.xml` file with the above content in `src/test/resources` and it works.

Comment: Nice, clean solution. The file can be named "logback-test.xml" as well and should be placed under 'src/test/resources' for clarity.

Comment: Yes, clarity is the reason why I named it `logback-text.xml`

Comment: what is the difference to my answer?

Answer (score 22):

To enable `application.properties` need to add an annotation `@SpringBootTest` to test class, read more [here](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4#spring-boot-1-4-simplifications).

Comment: @SpringBootTest is for integration tests and therefore the application.properties will be loaded. But for unit tests this is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 19):

I'm also looking for a solution to that, meanwhile I'm using the following solution:

this isn't the best but it works

```java
@BeforeClass
public static void setErrorLogging() {
   LoggingSystem.get(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()).setLogLevel(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME, LogLevel.ERROR);
}
```

`LoggingSystem`: a common abstraction over logging systems.

->

`get`: Detect and return the logging system in use. Supports Logback and Java Logging

`setLogLevel`:
Sets the logging level for a given logger.

Make sure to change back log level for all other test classes.

Hope it helps you, goodluck

Comment: This is the only way I ever got the logging to stop. Thank you

Comment: This is a usual bit of code to know in case you have to test what is getting logged without having a bunch of logger config files.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Just want to point out to use `@BeforeAll` if using JUnit5

Answer (score 10):

If your tests are annotated with `@DataJpaTest` you can switch Hibernate SQL logging off with:

```java
@DataJpaTest(showSql=false)
public class MyTest {
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationImportBackend.class, 
    initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles({ "test" })
public class BatchJobConfigurationTests {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but debug output still there.

Any more glue maybe?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.logging.logback), you can add a ***logback.xml*** file to the ***src/test/resources*** directory

> If you need to apply customizations to logback beyond those that can be achieved with  application.properties, you will need to add a standard logback configuration file. You can add a **logback.xml** file to the root of your classpath for logback to find. You can also use logback-spring.xml if you want to use the Spring Boot Logback extensions.

The example of the logback.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include
        resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <include
        resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
    <logger name="ua.com.company" level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.core " level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.beans" level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.context" level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.flyway" level="debag" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.transaction" level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="debug" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.test" level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="warn" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The Problem described here are project using maven modules. For simple projects putting logback.xml into src/test/resources is fine