# How to set Spring logging level while testing?

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging, logback

My Spring Boot testing stack is Maven + Surefire + JUnit4. I am annotating the tests with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`.

I have `application.properties` in my project root with this line:

```
logging.level.root=INFO
```

This controls the logging when running the Spring boot app and it works on normal runs.

However, whenever I run any JUnit4 tests, I am spammed by pages of DEBUG output like this:

```
....
17:43:20.500 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
17:43:20.500 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration'
17:43:20.501 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
17:43:20.502 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
....
```

All this spam makes it almost impossible to see the actually relevant parts. How can I apply the logging levels to test output?

I haven't set any logging explicitly, and according to the docs Logback is used by default.

Comment: Do you have an `application.properties` in `/test/resources`? You can also pass arbitrary properties when executing the tests with `-Dspring.foo.bar=baz`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just tried copying my application.properties there but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From a general perspective, you can provide a seperate `logback-test.xml`-file at the test-resource level. In this file you can add settings regarding the log-level targeted at the output you'd like such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.your.package" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.hibernate" level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.eclipse" level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="jndi" level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="WARN">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </logger>

  <root level="DEBUG">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Hope this helps you somewhat on the path to decreasing the log output. More is documented at logback's own page:

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Its mentioned in the top section:

> Let us begin by discussing the initialization steps that logback follows to try to configure itself: 
>   1.Logback tries to find a file called logback-test.xml in the classpath.
>
> 2.If no such file is found, logback tries to find a file called logback.groovy in the classpath.
>
> 3.If no such file is found, it checks for the file logback.xml in the classpath..
>
> 4.If no such file is found,  service-provider loading facility (introduced in JDK 1.6) is used to resolve the implementation of com.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator interface by looking up the file META-INF\services\ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator in the class path. Its contents should specify the fully qualified class name of the desired Configurator implementation.
>
> 5.If none of the above succeeds, logback configures itself automatically using the BasicConfigurator which will cause logging output to be directed to the console.

Comment: This helps a lot. Now I am only spammed by one page of Logback's output about setting logger levels. Looks like there is some other logger used before Logback is even set up.

Comment: Without the appender definition and references it actually works perfectly! Found that out by trying out an answer by Michael Hegner here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35254610/2445864

Comment: Nice! Removed my references as well in one of our applications, and it seems to remove all the overhead pointless output. Thanks! :)

Comment: If you want, you can edit your answer accordingly and I will accept it.

Comment: Just noticed that if you omit the CONSOLE definition, the sole existence of the file causes all logging output to go away. That said, this is the true answer.