# How to control log level in junit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, junit

I'm learning book Spring In Action 4th. And I read chapter2.

When I finished my first demo in chapter2, I found some problem. There are too much debug info when junit start.

[image: Too much debug info]

I do not know how to limit the output of junit. I tried to add a application.yml in src/test/resources folder, but it doesn't work.

Can someone give me some advice about how to control the level of log information in junit?

If you want to see my code, you can download my code from [Github](https://github.com/hellozjf/spring_in_action_chapter2).

My project use SpringBoot and Gradle.

Comment: All right. I have ask the wrong question. My question have been asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232827/spring-boot-test-ignores-logging-level. Sorry for asking this question.

Comment: No need to apologize. There are thousands of engineers all solving similar problems! We're going to have the same questions from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Create application-test.properties inside src/main/resources
and set logging level INFO

```
logging.level.root=INFO
```

and use  @ActiveProfiles("test") in your Test class

ex:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class Chapter2ApplicationTests
```

Also if you want change logging level in application level for all profile then change in application.yml

```
logging:
  level:
    root: info
soundsystem: info
```