# How to disable ch.qos.logback's own INFO messages in the run of the SpringBootTest during "mvn clean install"

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, logback, spring-logback

After a discussion with @RasmusFaber, the author of the most upvoted answer to
[How to prevent logback from outputting its own status at the start of every log when using a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3257154/2886891), I decided to create a new question as the solution in that question is not applicable to my problem.

---

I am building a Spring Boot application by Maven.

**I'd like to get rid of the log output from `ch.qos.logback` when I run `mvn clean install`.** I want to **disable the Logback's *own* status messages** as shown below.

I believe I applied all the hints given here in StackOverflow (including the above mentioned question) and everywhere else. Still I cannot make my build silent.

Please notice that all the log lines are `INFO`, not even `WARN`. So it is not a problem of missing `logback-access.xml` file. The logback framework show an `INFO` message even when if *does* find the file - see the 3rd line. Furthermore there are other `INFO` messages which are just a garbage.

#### Logback's own status messages I want to disable

```
10:51:16,066 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve[null] - Could NOT configuration file [C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.6036202080949559352.0\logback-access.xml] using property "catalina.base"
10:51:16,066 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve[null] - Could NOT configuration file [C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.6036202080949559352.0\logback-access.xml] using property "catalina.home"
10:51:16,066 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve[null] - Found [logback-access.xml] as a resource.
10:51:16,081 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
10:51:16,081 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
10:51:16,081 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.joran.JoranConfigurator@2831c178 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
10:51:16,081 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve[null] - Done configuring
```

#### Wider context

(when I temporarily set all the log levels to `DEBUG`)

```
...
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ my-application ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.xxxx.MyUnitTest
...
2020-11-27 14:06:33.590 DEBUG 2656 --- [           main] .c.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application started with classpath: unknown

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.4.RELEASE)

2020-11-27 14:06:33.675  INFO 2656 --- [           main] c.xxxx.MyUnitTest   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-11-27 14:06:33.676 DEBUG 2656 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class com.xxxx.MyApplication,class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener$BootstrapMarkerConfiguration
2020-11-27 14:06:33.694 DEBUG 2656 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'file:/C:/workspace/my-application/target/test-classes/application.properties' (classpath:/application.properties)
2020-11-27 14:06:33.695 DEBUG 2656 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@280d4882
...
2020-11-27 14:06:41.791 DEBUG 2656 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Starting filters
...
2020-11-27 14:06:41.803 DEBUG 2656 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Starting completed
############## START OF THE UNWANTED LOG ##############
14:06:41,811 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve[null] - Could NOT configuration file [C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.4629575738537063162.0\logback-access.xml] using property "catalina.base"
14:06:41,811 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve[null] - Could NOT configuration file [C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.4629575738537063162.0\logback-access.xml] using property "catalina.home"
14:06:41,812 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve[null] - Found [logback-access.xml] as a resource.
14:06:41,869 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
14:06:41,869 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
14:06:41,869 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.joran.JoranConfigurator@62732be7 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
14:06:41,869 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve[null] - Done configuring
############## END OF THE UNWANTED LOG ##############
2020-11-27 14:06:41.876 DEBUG 2656 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper        : Registered host [localhost]
2020-11-27 14:06:41.877 DEBUG 2656 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener  : Register Wrapper [default] in Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2020-11-27 14:06:41.878 DEBUG 2656 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener  : Register Wrapper [dispatcherServlet] in Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2020-11-27 14:06:41.878 DEBUG 2656 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener  : Register Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2020-11-27 14:06:41.879 DEBUG 2656 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener  : Register host [localhost] at domain [null] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
...
[INFO] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 54.705 s - in com.xxxx.MyUnitTest
```

#### Directory structure:

```
\---src
    \---test
        +---java
        |   ...
        \---resources
            |   application.properties
            |   logback-access.xml
            |   logback-test.xml
```

#### application.properties

```
logging.level.root=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR
logging.level.ch.qos.logback=ERROR
```

#### logback-test.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="ch.qos" level="ERROR"/>

    <root level="OFF">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

#### logback-access.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration />
```

#### POM.XML (only relevant lines left)

```xml
<project ...>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: We need some more information from you. During which step of the maven-process do you get the output? If _you_ recreate the directory structure described above, do you still get the output? I created the directory structure you described on my own machine and did not get the output. Tried adding a simple unit-test and still no log-output. Do you perhaps have an integration-test step in your pom.xml?

Comment: @RasmusFaber I have added a broader context, see my latest edit

Comment: Okay, so you clearly have something in your (test?) application context that enables logging. My suggestion would be to create the directory structure you have shown in this question and gradually copy more code from your real project until the problem occurs. Either that directly gives you your answer or you at least will have enough information that we are able to help you.

Comment: I know that I enable logging. What I want is to suppress logback from outputing its own status :) We want to see the output only if there are some errors.